# Generate a unique list of pairs from a set of values that does not match previous n pairings

Tags: python, list, set

I'm working in python for this problem.

Given a list of values that can increase or decrease in size between iterations (it will be padded to always be even)

```
users = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Create a new random set of pairings for the users (order does not matter)

```
pairs_2 = [[2,5],[4,6],[3,8],[1,7]]
```

and ensure that the pairing does not overlap with the previous n sets of pairs

```
pairs_1 = [[7,10],[3,5],[1,6],[2,8],[4,9]]
pairs_0 = [[2,4],[3,6],[1,5]]
```

My current implementation just involves generating a random set of pairs and then doing a set intersection against the previous n pairings to see if it is unique or not, this obviously does not scale well nor guarantee a solution in any reasonable time.

I've also tried to instead generate all possible combinations of pairs, and then find the difference between that and all previous pairings, but then there is the problem of selecting exactly users/2 pairs from the list that contains all users. It feels like the first half of this solution is good as it guarantees only new pairs, but then requires some additional logic to select the pairs.

Comment: How often does the list of users grow? Have you considered using `itertools.combinations` and selecting random samples from the entire set? Can you explain in more detail your use-case? Some expected inputs and outputs over the long term?

Comment: The list can grow/shrink between each call of the pairings, I would generally expect it to grow in size though between calls as more users are introduced to the system. Your suggestion is what I was doing in the last paragraph but as I pointed out you can't just select random samples from the set, the samples need to contain all the users in the users list (and only once) and also not overlap with the previous samples of pairs. This system should randomly match two users against each other who have not been previosuly matched in the last n matches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
myList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
oldList = []

for e in range(0,len(myList)):
    oldList.append([])
    for d in range(0,len(myList[e]),2):
       while True:
           f = False
           a = random.choice(myList[e])
           myList[e].remove(a)
           #print(myList,e)
           b = random.choice(myList[e])
           myList[e].remove(b)
           #print(myList,e)
           for c in oldList:
               if [a,b] in c:
                   myList[e].append(a)
                   myList[e].append(b)
                   #print("Runned")
                   f = True
           if f:
               f = False
               continue
           oldList[e].append([a,b])
           break
print(oldList)
```

All the result will be in oldList , It depend on which one you put in first

On your example , you should put in

```
myList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

And the result will be:

```
[[[6, 3], [5, 4], [2, 1]], [[5, 2], [10, 8], [3, 4], [1, 9], [7, 6]], [[6, 1], [8, 5], [7, 3], [4, 2]]]
```

And to get different pair out according to your example

```
pair_0 = oldList[0]
pair_1 = oldList[1]
pair_2 = oldList[2]
```

and the result will be

```
pair_0 = [[6, 3], [5, 4], [2, 1]]
pair_1 = [[5, 2], [10, 8], [3, 4], [1, 9], [7, 6]]
pair_2 = [[6, 1], [8, 5], [7, 3], [4, 2]]
```